# Sort ArrayList with Object's property

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

Here's an interesting metaphorical question:
Suppose I got a list of People, and the People are Grand-Pas ,fathers and kids.

```
Eg:(badly scrambled)
[Kid1, Kid2, GrandPa2, GrandPa3, Father1, Father3, Kid4, Father4, kid5]
```

I want to sort them like:

```
[Father1-Kid1, GrandPa2, Kid2, GrandPa3-Father3, Father4-Kid4, Kid5]
```

Just replace above list's - with , and it'll be a list afterall.

How can I sort such way? I tried Comparator and it got really complicated and many matches kills performance.

PS- I work in an environment where every ms JVM spend is accounted for, please guide me through some optimum way.

**Note**: cant use anything but List.

**What I've done so far:**
Put all grandPas in a list and then append father at related grandpa index, same do for Kids. This works fine I guess, could it be any faster?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Regarding your optimisation, focus on getting it to work first.

Comment: A computer can perform 50 million instructions in one milli-second. A milli-second is a long time for a computer.

Comment: Post the comparator you tried.

Comment: In Java 7 or earlier, it's possible to write a `Comparator` that does this sorting in about 10 lines. In Java 8 it becomes a single line. I won't simply post the answer since this looks like a homework assignment. But if you want help with what you've tried, post it and maybe we can help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you shouldn't be using a list. Use some tree structure to represent the hierarchy of the elements (or a forest if some elements are unrelated). Then a traversal of that tree can produce the elements in the order you wish.

Comment: He says he has to use a `List`, so this smells like homework to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can group all the entries by number into a List of collection for an id. e.g. everything ending in `1` goes into list[1] and everything ending in `2` goes into list [2]. Once the entries have been sorted into number, you can merge these entries as required.

This should give you close to O(N) time.